# How to convert an observableset to an observablelist

Tags: java, java-8, javafx-8, observable

I am trying to set items to a tableview but the setitems method expects an observablelist while I have an observableset in my model.The FXCollections utility class does not have a method for creating an observable list given an observable set.I tried casting but that caused a class cast exception (as expected).

Currently I am using this kind of code

```
new ObservableListWrapper<E>(new ArrayList<E>(pojo.getObservableSet()));
```

And I have some problems with it:

- Will editing this in the table update the underlying set as expected?
- Is it the 'right' way of doing this

So in short I need a style guide or best practice for converting between observable set and observable list because I expect to be doing this a lot when building a java fx GUI

Comment: Have you tried FXCollections.observableArrayList(pojo.getObservableSet().toArray());

Comment: Thanks I'll try this, but how is it better than my current method above?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Will editing this in the table update the underlying set as expected ?**

No because, you are doing a copy of the set:

```
new ArrayList<E>(pojo.getObservableSet())
```

**Is it the 'right' way of doing this ?**

I think the right way is not doing that. `Set` are not `List` and vice versa. Both have specific contraints. For example, the lists are ordered and sets contains no duplicate elements.

Moreover, nor [`FXCollections`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/FXCollections.html) neither [`Bindings`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/binding/Bindings.html) provides this kind of stuff.

**I would like the collection to remain as a set to enforce uniqueness**

I guess you could write a custom `ObservableList`, for example the [`Parent::children`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Parent.html#getChildren--) have a similar behavior. It throws an `IllegalArgumentException` if a duplicate children is added. If you look at the source code, you will see that it is a `VetoableListDecorator` extension. You could write your own:

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;

import com.sun.javafx.collections.VetoableListDecorator;

public class CustomObservableList<E> extends VetoableListDecorator<E> {

    public CustomObservableList(ObservableList<E> decorated) {
        super(decorated);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProposedChange(List<E> toBeAdded, int... indexes) {
        for (E e : toBeAdded) {
            if (contains(e)) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Duplicament element added");
            }
        }
    }
}

class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Object o1 = new Object();
        Object o2 = new Object();

        Set<Object> set = new HashSet<Object>();
        set.add(o1);
        CustomObservableList<Object> list = new CustomObservableList<Object>(FXCollections.observableArrayList(set));
        list.add(o2);
        list.add(o1); // throw Exception
    }
}
```

Comment: So back to the underlying problem, how do I get the tableview to display the items collection that is based on a set? I would like the collection to remain as a set to enforce uniqueness

Comment: Please be aware that this uses the internal "private" API of JavaFX. This can potentially break (especially with Jigsaw, although there will be a command-line switch to make it work - at least with JDK 9). If you think this API is useful an issue could be created to make it a candidate for inclusion in the public API.

Comment: You forgot a closing parentheses -> `new ArrayList<E>(pojo.getObservableSet())` (Edits require more than 6 characters or I'd do it myself)

Answer (score 2):

Just in Case someone stumbles over this question looking for a one-way to convert an ObservableSet into an ObservableList... I post my solution. It doesn't support feeding back data to the set (which in my opinion wouldn't be nice since TableView doesn't have a concept of not being able to change a value) but supports updates of the set and preserves the (in this case) sorted order.

```
package de.fluxparticle.lab;

import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.collections.ObservableSet;
import javafx.collections.SetChangeListener;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.TreeSet;

import static javafx.collections.FXCollections.observableSet;

/**
 * Created by sreinck on 23.01.17.
 */
public class Set2List extends Application {

    private final ObservableSet<Integer> setModel = observableSet(new TreeSet<Integer>());

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        TableView<Integer> tableView = new TableView<>();
        addColumn(tableView, "Number");

        ObservableList<Integer> list = convertSetToList(setModel);
        tableView.setItems(list);

        Random rnd = new Random();
        scheduleTask(Duration.millis(1000), () -> setModel.add(rnd.nextInt(10)));

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(tableView, 800, 600));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Set2List");
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private static void scheduleTask(Duration interval, Runnable task) {
        Timeline timeline = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(interval, event -> task.run()));
        timeline.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
        timeline.play();
    }

    private static ObservableList<Integer> convertSetToList(ObservableSet<Integer> set) {
        ObservableList<Integer> list = FXCollections.observableArrayList(set);

        set.addListener((SetChangeListener<Integer>) change -> {
            if (change.wasAdded()) {
                Integer added = change.getElementAdded();
                int idx = -Collections.binarySearch(list, added)-1;
                list.add(idx, added);
            } else {
                Integer removed = change.getElementRemoved();
                int idx = Collections.binarySearch(list, removed);
                list.remove(idx);
            }
        });

        return list;
    }

    private static void addColumn(TableView<Integer> tableView, String text) {
        TableColumn<Integer, String> column = new TableColumn<>(text);
        column.setCellValueFactory(param -> new SimpleStringProperty(param.getValue().toString()));
        tableView.getColumns().add(column);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```