# Which data structure use for a TableView that doesn't allow duplicate items?

Tags: java, javafx, tableview, javafx-8, observablelist

I've tried to find a data structure that can be used for hold TableView data but which doesn't allows duplicated items. If I didn't need an observable, more precisely a ObservableList, for TableView,  I would use a HashSet but I can't.

I have considered create a new class which implements ObsevableList for this because I really don't want to have 2 data structures, ObservableSet and ObservableList, for example.

Does anyone knows any solution?

Comment: Just work with an `ObservableSet` and add a listener to it that updates the tableview list on adding/removing an object.

Comment: But in that way I'm using 2 lists, double memory, right?

Comment: Look at the [first answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24808631/9662601) of the referenced post. It describes how to create a simple observable list yourself, which does not allow duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

First Determine the equality condition and what makes an Object duplicate. Then override the `equals` and `hashcode` methods in your class. (If you are using classes like String or Integer, these should already be well defined.). Then when you are trying to add an Object to your table you just have to check that if the table already contains that item:

```
if(!table.getItems().contains(newItem)) table.getItems.add(newItem);
```

or if you are not adding Objects one by one, you can use the Java8 Stream API:

```
table.getItems().setAll(table.getItems().stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList()));
```